# Github V3 API : list contributors

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have read the following doc (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) to list contributors on a repository I have worked on, and I can see that one person who committed several times does not appear, and myself only have 3 contributions whereas I pushed most of our 301 commits.

I don't really get what this end-point returns, but it does not look accurate. The doc is not very detailed about that, does anybody know something that might explain it ?

Comment: Do you have more than 500 contributors? Does setting `anon` to `true` return more results?

Comment: @TriskalJM Your second question makes me think you were on the right track. I'll include the answer I got from the API's support.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I submitted my question to the Github API's support, and they made me an amazingly detailed answer. Here it is (shortened):

> It looks like your missing commits were authored with an email address
>   not linked to your GitHub profile. You can find the missing email by
>   adding ".patch" to the end of a commit URL, then looking at the
>   "From:" line. Once you have the email, you can link it to your profile
>   by following these instructions:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user
>
> After you link your email to your account, any valid missing
>   contributions will be backfilled and new ones should show up
>   automatically.
>
> For example, when I check out the Projet-merou's commit history:
>
> https://github.com/jxw1102/Projet-merou/commits/master
>
> When I choose the latest commit with your GitHub username as its
>   author and add .patch to the URL like so:
>
> https://github.com/jxw1102/Projet-merou/commit/f5bf30243ab99efc40802d3d78c08e49839ec9c9.patch
>
> I see this on the second line:
>
> ```
> From: Dicee courtinot.david@orange.fr
> ```
>
> Adding that email will backfill any missing valid contributions. After
>   you do that, calling the API should show the expected result.
>
> ### API Endpoints: Contributors and Contributors Statistics
>
> I have written up some notes about each endpoint below. Let me know
>   if you have any questions!
>
> **/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors**
>
> When you call `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contributors`, the GitHub API
>   will list contributors to the specified repository, sorted by the
>   number of commits per contributor in descending order. Contributors
>   data is cached for performance reasons. This endpoint may return
>   information that is a few hours old. Git contributors are identified
>   by author email address. This API attempts to group contribution
>   counts by GitHub user, across all of their associated email addresses.
>   For performance reasons, only the first 500 author email addresses in
>   the repository will be linked to GitHub users. The rest will appear as
>   anonymous contributors without associated GitHub user information.
>
> If you call this endpoint with `anon=1` specified, the API will return
>   a count of all commits on the default branch, including commits that
>   aren't associated with any user on GitHub. Here's an example:
>
> https://api.github.com/repos/jxw1102/Projet-merou/contributors?anon=1
>
> When `anon=1` isn't specified like this:
>
> https://api.github.com/repos/jxw1102/Projet-merou/contributors
>
> notice how the results only show commits associated with some GitHub
>   user and doesn't count merge commits.
>
> **/repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors**
>
> When you call `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors`, the GitHub
>   API will return the contributors list with additions, deletions, and
>   commit counts. The total denotes the total number of commits authored
>   by the contributor.
>
> Does that help?
>
> All the best,
>   Francis
>   @francisfuzz
>   GitHub Support

Comment: It looks like this API endpoint is not really reliable for not-so-famous public repositories as it tends to return an empty object as the body of the response instead of the full stats for the contributions. Retrying a few times and waiting for a few seconds will in the end give the expected result. Not sure what is happening behind the scenes but this is worth noting as it looks like GitHub does not index the stats for all repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after I've merged devel to master. There were contributors missing. GitHub support replied:

> That's expected behavior -- please read the documentation for that
>   endpoint:
>
> https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors
>
> "This endpoint may return information that is a few hours old because
>   the GitHub REST API v3 caches contributor data to improve
>   performance."
>
> So, you might need to wait a few hours to get updated data.